# contract deployment ubuntu 16.04

Tags: smart-contract

I am having issues deploying contracts on a single node test environment. I used the setup scripts and played around with the config.ini file. Everything runs and all the commands at least regarding cleos seem to be working but I have 2 issues. deploying contracts i keep getting

Error 3160009: No wast file found
Error Details:
no wasm file found

No matter which contract I try to deploy this happens. Also I noticed in my config.ini file I could not find a genesis.json even though i ran nodeos and closed it. Then proceeded to run again when using cleos.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by changing config.ini http to 0.0.0.0:8888 & by changing the parameters for the path flags in "cleos set contract". As well as editing the contract and generating a WAST file..

Answer (score 0):

In my contract folder, I added the following script called `compile` (`chmod +x compile`) to compile and publish the contract to my local test net.

For this script to work, your contract folder, the names of your contract files and the account hosting the contract must be the same name.

```
CONTRACT=${PWD##*/} 

rm -Rf $CONTRACT.was* $CONTRACT.abi
eosiocpp -o $CONTRACT.wast $CONTRACT.cpp
eosiocpp -g $CONTRACT.abi $CONTRACT.hpp
cleos set contract $CONTRACT ../$CONTRACT -p $CONTRACT@active
```

So whenever I have done my changes and I want to compile and publish my contract I will `cd` to my contract folder and execute `./compile`.

Comment: That would definetly make things easier.Thanks for the tip